# How to edit TCP window size from iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp, tcp-window-scaling

There is TCPMSS target to edit MSS value of connections (including forwarded).

How to edit window size (for example, cap to some maximum value) by iptables rule?

Expecting something like

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 1234 -j TCPWINDOW --tcpwindow-set 'min(val,100000)'
```

Comment: Have to admit, pretty curious as to why you would want to do this?

Comment: I'm playing with traffic shaping currently and looking for various ways to limit inbound TCP traffic. I think capping the receive window + adding some delay (`tc qdisc ... netem delay ...`) can more or less cleanly set the speed of receiving without crude things like intentionally dropping valid packets.

Comment: Dropping packets is a valid way to inform about congestion. Other way is using ECN (rfc3168), if both ends support it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change TCP window from iptables you need to:

- checkout https://github.com/p5n/ipt_tcpwin
- build both modules using "make"
- add iptables rule, for example:

`iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 80 --tcp-flags SYN,ACK SYN,ACK -j TCPWIN --tcpwin-set 1000`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the option **--set-mss** to achieve this.

Example:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -o ppp0 -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1492
```

Documentation: http://www.linuxtopia.org/Linux_Firewall_iptables/x4700.html

Comment: MSS and TCP Window are similar but still different things.

Comment: MSS is akin to IP MTU, so instead of reducing the window size you'd get smaller messages than the path MTU allows for, but still the same window size.